# Why XDocument.Load() and XmlDocument.LoadXml() can't load XML with comments contains more than two "--" symbols?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have a problem loading an xml document contains comments like this:

```
<!--- value --->
    <item attribute = "somevalue"/>
```

I get this error with both XDocument.Load() and XmlDocument.LoadXml() methods :
An XML comment cannot contain '--', and '-' cannot be the last character.

But XML specs on MSDN have an example with comments like this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256201(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256201%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

What's wrong in my xml syntax? Is it important to end the comment with "-->" sequence, or what?
Can I exclude comment while loading XML?

Comment: Yes I think, comments can be ignored prior to loading XML. But have you checked your XML document is well-formed after using `--->` instead of `-->` to close the comments?

Comment: No it doesn't. It has an example like this: <!--- ... --> (3 beginning hyphens, and 2 ending hyphens), which is valid, yours contains ---> (3 ending hyphens), which is not. "--" is not allowed in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `<!--- value --->` says comment are not closed yet. Actually `--` not permitted within XML comment.

Comment must end with this `-->`tag.

Validate your XML [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) or [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/).

**Input XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- comment in -->
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from> 
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <!-- comment in -->
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  <!--- comment in --->
</note>
```

**Validation Result**:

[image]

For ignoring comments prior to loading XML you can see **selected answer** at following link:

[How to ignore comments when reading a XML file into a XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875674/how-to-ignore-comments-when-reading-a-xml-file-into-a-xmldocument).

Comment: Thank you so much, validator shows that my document is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a xml parser error

Try this: using `String.Replace`

```
xmlString.Replace("---", "--");
```