# How to include XmlComments for Swagger in only one API Controller (not all Controllers in the same project)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to add more information about one of my API routes using Swashbuckle. I only need to enable XML comments files in Swagger for one of my API routes. But, checking 'XML documentation file:' in Project -> Properties would force me to put XML comments throughout the whole project. Is there a way to achieve this?

For this I've included XML comments, made sure build's Output has the 'XML documentation file:' checked, and have

```
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

in my SwaggerConfig.cs.

Comment: Turn off the warning in all the other source files.

Comment: as far as i uderstood request:
one approach : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875674/how-to-ignore-comments-when-reading-a-xml-file-into-a-xmldocument

another one is use [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

use [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] on all controllers you want to remove from documentation

Answer (score 0):

At this point, any classes or methods that are NOT annotated with XML comments will trigger a build warning. To suppress this, enter the warning code "1591" into the "Suppress warnings" field in the properties dialog or add 1591 to the  section of your .csproj project file.